# jquery typeahead and address picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

With the release of [bootstrap 3.0](http://getbootstrap.com/) the typeahead plugin has been removed and replaced with [Twitters typeahead plugin](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/).  Any idea how I can use this in conjunction with the [addresspicker plugin](https://github.com/flevour/jquery-addressPicker).

My old code worked like this:

```
    $('#location').addressPicker({
          boundElements: {
              '#wizard .Country': function(data) {
                  var result = '';
                  $.each(data.address_components, function (index, value) {
                      if (value.types.indexOf('country') !== -1) {
                          result = value.long_name;
                      }
                  });
                  return result;
              },                  
              '#wizard .State': 'administrative_area_level_1',
              '#wizard .City': 'locality',
              '#wizard .PostalCode': 'postal_code',
              '#wizard .Lat': 'lat',
              '#wizard .Lng': 'lng'
          }
    });
```

The event trigger for the new type ahead looks like this:

```
$('#location').typeahead({                                
         /* ??? */
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I the first place, why should you replace the "old" typeahead plugin? Twitters typeahead plugin is not bundled with the Twitter's Bootstrap 3 Javascript Plugins.

In your code you could include both like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="bootstrap3/bootstrap-master/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
<!-- down load the required version here: https://github.com/flevour/jquery-addressPicker/blob/master/demo/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js-->
```

Second to use Twitters typeahead instead of the "old" typeahead you don't need to change your call (only). The addresspicker plugin calls typeahead with a .typeahead() on a (form element). You have to change this call or at least the options for it in the source code of the addresspicker plugin.

If address picker works well i should not try to change the typeahead.